# How make items in combobox appear in one selection instead of selecting them only one by one?

Tags: pyqt4, qtablewidget, qcombobox

How do you get items that are added to qcomboBox with click of push button to appear as example: '10, 23, 56, 14, 57, ... ' instead of only having them all appear in the drop down menu and only selecting them one by one? Here is my code:

```py
def setup(self, Dialog):   
        ...
    self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(Dialog)
    self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 431, 22))
    self.comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox"))

    self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(Dialog)
    self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 470, 651, 71))
    self.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
    self.tableWidget.setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideRight)
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalScrollMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerItem)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(129)
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableWidget"))
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    for i in range(0, self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, i, item)

    self.pushButton_7 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
    self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 650, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_7"))
    self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.additem)

def additem(self):
    for i in range(0, self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0,i)
        if item != None:
            text = item.text()
            self.comboBox.addItem(text)
```

Comment: So you want all text from cells of one row in table widget to be added as one item(one row) in combo box?

Comment: Yes, separated with commas. All my input data should appear as one item. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `additem` method should look like this:

```
def additem(self):
    text = ""
    for i in range(0, self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0,i)
        if item != None:
            text += item.text() + ", "

    self.comboBox.addItem(text[:-2])
```